# Passing javascript dynamic parameter in function included in string

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic

I have a simple javascript problem.
Here is an example:

```
function Test(Var)
{
...
}

var Variable='Hello';

var Message='<a href="javascript:;" onClick="Test(' + Variable + ')">Click me</a>';
```

As you can guess, the way Im trying to pass the **Variable** is wrong.
Can you please help me?

Comment: Eh? You're not passing Variable. You're not even calling Test. What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add quotes:

```
var Message='<a href="javascript:;" onClick="Test(\'' + Variable + '\')">Click me</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem of quotes. Try with escape:

```
function Test(Var)
{
...
}

var Variable='Hello';

var Message='<a href="javascript:;" onClick="Test(\'' + Variable + '\')">Click me</a>';
```