# Passing dynamic variable to an outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck on some javascript here. I need to pass a dynamic variable/variables to an outside function. Here is the function which generates the PHP webpage URL, which I am ultimately trying to POST some data to(not the full function, only the important parts):

```
var id = "";
var name = "";
var url = "";


function initialize () {
  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml1.php", function (data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var description1 = markers[i].getAttribute("description");
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var url = "markerpages.php?name=" + name + "&id=" + id;
        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + description1;
        var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
                '<div id="siteNotice">' +
                '</div>' +
                '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + name + '</h1>' +
                '<div id="bodyContent">' +
                '<p>' + description1 + '</p>' + 
                '<p><a href="'+ url +'" onclick="postData(url)">Link to PHP web page</a>' +
                '</p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>';`
```

I have the 'url' variable globally defined and then my postData function looks like this and is outside of the initialize function:

```
function postData(arg) {
  alert("Url: "+url+"Name: "+name+"ID: "+id);
    $(document).ready(function () { 

            var href = $('.postData').attr('href');
            var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
            var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var url = "markerpages.php?name=" + name + "&id=" + id;

            window.location.href = href;
            console.log("outside ajax is working");
            console.log(url);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: ' + url + ',
                data: {
                    source1: "some text",
                    source2: "some text 2"},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(url);
                    console.log("inside ajax is working");
                }
            });

        });
}
```

the jquery is firing onclick, but url is coming back as undefined, so I just need to bring in that url variable which is generated based on a marker name stored in a database. I am a beginner, so this may be very simple. I looked around the forums and documentation, but have not been able to figure this out for many hours, haha.

Sincere thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by "defined globally"? I only see a `var url` and it's inside of the `document.ready` closure, plus the `url` being passed as an argument. Those two are conflicting at the very least

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable outside the scope of all functions like this:

```
 //Declare the three variables globally
 var url = "";
 var name = "";
 var id = "";
 ...

 function initialize () {

   ...
   //id and name are local to this function, if you want them to be global as well
   //declare them outside the scope of all functions along with url variable

   //Assign them suitable values
   id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
   name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
   url = "markerpages.php?name=" + name + "&id=" + id;

  ...
 }

function postData(arg) {

   //Use all the variables here directly for example you could just try alerting them
   alert("Url: "+url+"Name: "+name+"ID: "+id);

 }
```

The problem in your case is that "url" variable is **not** global. You declare the url variable in `postData(arg)` and `initialize()` functions separately and therefore this variable is local in scope to these functions.

Also, in the `postData(arg)` function you do this:

```
  var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
  var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
  var url = "markerpages.php?name=" + name + "&id=" + id;
```

However, the `markers` array is traversed in `initialize()` function and not in the `postData` function. If you want to access the 'id' and 'name' variable in this context as well. Just declare them **once** outside the scope of all functions and initialize or update them in any context later on like I show with the 'url' variable.

Comment: So I just tried bringing all three of those variable in (and actually tried that before) but when I bring those variables in, I get "i is not defined". so do I need to bring in the whole array of variables? If I only bring in the url variable to the function, I get "id is not defined" or "name is not defined"

Comment: @ambe5950, you can't bring all the three variables inside `postData()` function because `i` and `markers` array are not defined in that function's scope. You already assign 'name' and 'id' a suitable value inside the `initialize` function where the `markers` array is getting read. If however you want to use the 'name' and 'id' variable inside the 'postData' function as well. Just declare them outside all the functions and assign them values like you do. See the edited answer for the same.

Comment: Got it, (and updated my code) But what if in place of assigning suitable values, those [i] values are filled in by database query? I have a ton of markers but need the name and url of each one to be generated in the initialize function and the data POSTed to the server.

Comment: The code that you posted and the variable names will just store the **last** value of the `markers` array because they're defined as strings. Your question was to understand why you get the url variable to be undefined in `postData()` function. It's because you define it local to a scope of that function. If however you want to store the values of 'name' and corresponding 'url' for **every** i, then the name,id and url variables will be arrays and not strings.

Comment: sorry to keep bugging you on this (and thanks for all the help so far) So when I click on one of my marker links its associated url looks something like "http://127.0.0.1/PhpProject3/markerpages.php?name=Blackberry%20Courts&id=33" but I need to have that specific url to know where to POST to. Right now, url, id, and name are still blank.

Comment: @ambe5950, I get your point. You're generating a url associated with every marker. So you should just have a global array containing those urls. But if I understand correctly, the `postData` function accepts an argument right. So iff you are calling `postData` from within the `initialize` function, you can just pass the url like `postData(url)` where the variables 'url', 'name' and 'id' are simple strings like I've mentioned in the answer.

Comment: exactly, Alright I will give that a go. Thanks for all the help. Ill let you know if I get it working

Comment: found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859917/passing-javascript-dynamic-parameter-in-function-included-in-string

Comment: Well it's great that you got your problem sorted. Please consider editing your question to reflect the same or add an answer to your question and accept it so that others in a similar problem can also benefit out of it.